# boost::program_options : how to add a program description text

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I would like that a text is printed before the description of the allowed options when I print my options_description. Something like :

```
This program counts from 1 to 10. <--- this is what is missing

Generic options:
-h [ --help ]         Produce help message.
-v [ --version ]      Show program name/version banner and exit.
```

Currently I add it by hand :

```
if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << "options_description\n\n" << my_options_description << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Is it possible to store this directly in the options_description object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `options_description` class is for describing the *options*, not the program. The Program_options library isn't really intended for general-purpose documentation.

I suppose you could abuse the label:

```
po::options_description options(
  "This program counts from 1 to 10.\n\nGeneric options");
```

Comment: Seems like it would fit the bill, but you'd run into problems when using [multiple options descriptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2444931). But, +1 nevertheless.

Comment: somewhat easier is on `if(vm.count("help"))` printing a separate string containing a formatted usage + synopsis before writing the options themselves.

Comment: That's exactly what's already shown in the question, @Template. I'm not sure that's "easier," as you say; looks like about the same amount of work either way.

Comment: I tend to do `std::cout << usage << options << '\n' << synopsis << '\n';` where `options` is a `po::options_description` object, and `usage` and `synopsis` are `std::string`. The advantage is more control over indentation. Also, synopsis comes after option description in most unix utilities, and that is otherwise hard to add.